# Hibernate HQL keeps throwing 'QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token'

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql, hibernate-mapping

I have a one-to-many relationship between `UpdatesEntity` and `EntriesEntity` (an `Update` has many `Entries`). The relationship looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entries", schema = "", catalog = "whatever")
public class EntriesEntity {
    ....
    private UpdatesEntity update;

    ....

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "update_id")
    public UpdatesEntity getUpdate() {
        return update;
    }

    public void setUpdate(UpdatesEntity update) {
        this.update = update;
    }
```

I am trying to run the following query

```
FROM UpdatesEntity u, EntriesEntity e WHERE e.update = u
```

but I keep on getting:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: e near line 1, column 99 [FROM com.whatever.model.beans.UpdatesEntity u, com.whatever.model.beans.EntriesEntity e WHERE e.update = u]
```

However, if in the query I replace `e.update` with `e.description`, for example, it works. The only problem seems to be when trying to access the `update` field of the `EntriesEntity`.

I am now very puzzled because I have tried this with what I believe to be an exact copy of this relationship, but that works, while this doesn't.

I have been debugging this for hours to no avail. Any idea would be very welcome!

Comment: Having a column called `update` is probably a very bad idea, since this has a special meaning in both HQL and SQL.  Why don't you try renaming this column, to find out whether this is what's causing the problem?

Comment: Why not renaming to updateEntity ? (private UpdatesEntity updateEntity;) ? There is probably a conflict with the SQL keyword Update.

Comment: Well, now I feel stupid. This seems to have been the problem. Intellij IDEA has syntax highlighting for HQL queries and it reinforced my belief that this couldn't have been an issue. Thanks, guys! @DavidWallace - I would like to have an accepted answer for this question and you answered first, so you could post an answer and I will accept. Thanks, @JFPicard!

Answer (score 0):

If you defined relationship correctly for  `UpdatesEntity` and `EntriesEntity`, your can use "join" like below:

Inner Join:

```
FROM UpdatesEntity u inner join u.entriesEntity e
```

or left outer join:

```
FROM UpdatesEntity u left outer join u.entriesEntity e
```

or, get entriesEntity  directly from UpdatesEntity after load an object of UpdatesEntity, like this:

```
UpdatesEntity myObj = session.get(UpdatesEntity.class, id);
Set<EntriesEntity> ent = myObj.getEntriesEntity()//assume you used "Set"
```

In above join, you may add "where" condition with individual property, such as "where e.aaa=xxx". I don't think you can use entity object directly in "where", like yours "WHERE e.update = u".

Answer (score 0):

You don;t need a Cartesian Product, since you can use a JOIN:

```
SELECT e
FROM EntriesEntity e 
JOIN FETCH e.update
```